# I want to make the sound change depending on whether the left shift key is used or not

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to change the sound in real time when I press the left shift key(= Input.GetButton("Walk")), and when I release the left key, I want to make the sound change again. However, if when I start walking with press the W key and press the left shift key, the sound will not change. Also, if I release the left shift key when  I  start walking with press the W key and the left shift key, the sound does not change.

If you change

```
 Input.GetButton("Walk")
```

to

```
hAxis != 0
```

and

```
!Input.GetButton("Walk")
```

to

```
vAxis != 0
```

it works well

```
void Move() 
{
    moveVec = new Vector3(hAxis, 0, vAxis).normalized;

    // Camera
    moveVec = cameraTransform.TransformDirection(moveVec); 

    moveVec *= moveSpeed;
    moveVec.y = 0;

    if (isSide && moveVec == sideVec)
    {
        moveVec = Vector3.zero;
    }
    
    // move
    transform.position += moveVec * moveSpeed * (wDown ? 0.3f : 1f) * Time.deltaTime;

    // animation
    anim.SetBool("isRun", moveVec != Vector3.zero);
    anim.SetBool("isWalk", wDown);

    // sound
    if (moveVec != Vector3.zero) 
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Walk") && !isRunningSound)
        {
            Debug.Log("walk");
            CancelInvoke(currentSound);
            currentSound = "WalkSound";
            InvokeRepeating(currentSound, 0f, 0.7f);
            isRunningSound = true;               
        } 
        else if(!Input.GetButton("Walk") && !isRunningSound) 
        {
            Debug.Log("run");
            CancelInvoke(currentSound);
            currentSound = "RunSound";
            InvokeRepeating(currentSound, 0f, 0.3f);
            isRunningSound = true;
        } 
    }
    else
    {
        CancelInvoke(currentSound);
        
        
        
        isRunningSound = false;
    }
}

void RunSound() 
{
    audio.clip = audioRun;
    audio.Play();
}

void WalkSound() 
{
    audio.clip = audioWalk;
    audio.Play();
}
```

Comment: what is `wDown` and why are you not reusing it?

Comment: wDown is a bool value that receives a true value when it is Input.GetButton("Walk")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of possible problems:

When you call `Play()` on an audiosource over and over, you will just keep restarting it, resulting in the source not playing the full sound. You should also make sure to stop the audio source before switching effects.

You also might be overcomplicating things a little bit, here's an updated code:

```cs
if (Input.GetButton("Walk") && !isRunningSound)
        {
            if(audio.clip != audioWalk){


               audio.Stop();
               audio.clip = audioWalk;
                audio.Play();
             }
            Debug.Log("walk");

                 
        } 
        else if(!isRunningSound) 
        {
            Debug.Log("run");
if(audio.clip != audioRun){
audio.Stop();
audio.clip = audioRun;
audio.Play();
}
           
            
            
        }
```

This should work without the need for any auxillary functions, provided you have assigned audio and set it to Loop.